ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oopclasses'

I am finding it difficult to import flower.py into tests/test_flower.py's namespace. I have tried every combination of the import statement but it still a nightmare.
Also, I tried putting __init__.py in every directory but still has not worked
Also fascinating is I decided to put the test_flower.py file into the same directory as the flower.py, and the importation worked correctly
Where can be the problem?

Do you run test_flower.pydirectly? by which command?

test_flower is in the test folder. that is why...

Move tests/ from oopclasses/ directory to project directory, then run your tests from project directory.
